# VS Code Unresponsive to new Flutter project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to this so I apologize if there's something obvious I'm doing wrong, but essentially, as the title says, when using VS Code and opening up the Command Palette all goes well and I am able to select 'Flutter: New Project', however once I select this, the bottom of the screen briefly reads 'Activating Extensions' and then nothing else happens. No Flutter Project is opened, no opportunity to select 'Application', etc. but also no error message. Would love to know if anyone might know what's going wrong.

I've already installed Flutter/Dart and have ran flutter doctor in the terminal and it reads as having everything successfully established. Have also rebooted everything a couple of times for good measure. Any ideas?

Comment: Try uninstalling all the extensions related to dart & flutter and after that delete the data from~/.vscode/extensions. Again reinstall those extensions. Hope this  helps